# MYSQL Matching Samples by weight

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I would like to reduce the number of samples by matching them for a specific product.

Conditions :  The total weight does not exceed 200 pounds AND
Reduce lightest and heavier samples wherever it’s possible

```
CREATE TABLE 'sample' ('product' TEXT,'id_sample' INTEGER,'weight_sample' INTEGER);
INSERT INTO 'sample' ('product','id_sample','weight_sample') VALUES 
 ('A','1001','160'), 
 ('A','1002','40'), 
 ('A','1003','5'), 
 ('B','1004','195'), 
 ('B','1005','190'), 
 ('B','1006','180'), 
 ('B','1007','160'), 
 ('B','1008','26'), 
 ('B','1009','12');
```

Table

| product | id_sample | weight_sample |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1001 | 160 |
| A | 1002 | 40 |
| A | 1003 | 5 |
| B | 1004 | 195 |
| B | 1005 | 190 |
| B | 1006 | 180 |
| B | 1007 | 160 |
| B | 1008 | 26 |
| B | 1009 | 12 |

Output :

| product | id_sample1 | weight_sample1 | id_sample2 | weight_sample2 | total_weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1001 | 160 | 1003 | 5 | 165 |
| B | 1006 | 180 | 1009 | 12 | 192 |
| B | 1007 | 160 | 1008 | 26 | 186 |

[OUTPUT IMG][1]

Greetings

EDIT :

```
WITH 
     M (product, N_ref, MIN_weight) as (
        SELECT product, count(id_sample), min(weight_sample) FROM sample GROUP BY product)
    ,X as (SELECT sample.*, M."MIN_weight", row_number() over(partition by sample.product order by weight_sample DESC, id_sample) as RN 
           FROM sample, M WHERE sample.product = M.product and M."MIN_weight"+sample.weight_sample <= 200)
    ,Z (product, id_sample, weight_sample, RN, Id2_compl, MIN_weight) as (
        SELECT X.product, X.id_sample, X.weight_sample, X.RN, (M.N_ref-X.RN+1), M."MIN_weight"
        FROM X, M
        WHERE X.product = M.product)
    ,T (id_sample2, id_2, weight_sample2, product) as (
        SELECT Z2.id_sample, Z2.id2_compl, Z2.weight_sample, Z2.product
        FROM Z, Z Z2 
        WHERE Z2.RN = Z.id2_compl and Z.product = Z2.product)
SELECT 
    Z.product, Z.id_sample as "id_sample1", Z.weight_sample as "weight_sample1",
    T.id_sample2, T.weight_sample2, (Z.weight_sample+T.weight_sample2) as "weight_total"
FROM Z, T
WHERE Z.product = T.product and Z.RN = T.id_2 and "id_sample1" <> "id_sample2" 
order by Z.product, weight_total
```

Here my code so far, but feel way too complicate and not working (!)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jZ8r.png

Comment: ".... for a specific product"   => Please clarify.

Comment: Why a combination of 160+5 (first line in your output)? There is also a sample with weight_sample=40,   and 160+40 does not exceed 200, => Please clarify

Comment: BTW: I created a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b0946cd051db7d26501df6904d77008)  with just the data...

Comment: 160 + 5 because  we tend to reduce lightest samples wherever it’s possible

Comment: "for a specific product"  product A can not be match with product B

Comment: [terminology] "... reduce the lightest ..." -- Do you mean "... exclude the lightest ..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select
    a.product, a.id, a.weight, b.product, b.id, b.weight, a.weight + b.weight as total
from
    sample a inner join sample b on a.product = b.product and a.id < b.id
where
    a.weight + b.weight <= 200 and not exists(
        select 1 from sample x
        where x.product = a.product and x.id <> a.id and x.id <> b.id and
        (x.weight + a.weight <= 200 and x.weight + a.weight > a.weight + b.weight or
         x.weight + b.weight <= 200 and x.weight + b.weight > a.weight + b.weight)
    )
```

Gives the correct result except it wants to combine A 1001 with A 1002 to get a total of 200.

First we join on product and a.id < b.id because we don't want (a, a) or having both (a, b) and (b, a), one is enough.

Then the total weight conditions are applied and then we check with the not exists if a sample exists which can be combined with the ones selected to give a higher weight still <= 200. So each sample is only used once (or never) in the output.

Comment: Thanks à lot !! Elegant and short code :D

One remark, like you said :with your code, the id_sample 1001 & 1002 are matching instead the 1001 a 1003 specify  in my conditions : reduce lightest and heavier samples wherever it’s possible

But I can deal with it and start working !

Thank you for your time.